# python "if" versus "and" function execution order

Tags: python, function, python-2.7

Is there any functional difference between the following two blocks of code? I'm concerned mainly with the order in which the functions are called. Are functions executed sequentially in the first `if` statement?

First,

```
if func1() and func2() and func3() and func4():
    do stuff
```

Second,

```
if func1():
    if func2():
        if func3():
            if func4():
                do stuff
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, Python evaluates expressions from left to right. The functions will be called in the same order. From the [reference documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#evaluation-order):

> Python evaluates expressions from left to right.

Moreover, `func2()` will not be called if `func1()` returned a false value, both when using `and` and when nesting `if` expressions. Quoting the [boolean operations documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#boolean-operations):

> The expression `x and y` first evaluates `x`; if `x` is false, its value is returned; otherwise, `y` is evaluated and the resulting value is returned.

Because in the expression `func1() and func2()`, `func2()` will not be evaluated if `func1()` returned a false value, `func2()` is not called at all.

You could use a third alternative here using the [`all()` function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#all):

```
functions = (func1, func2, func3, func4)
if all(f() for f in functions):
```

which would again only call functions as long as the preceding function returned a true value and call the functions in order.

The `all()` approach *does* require that `func1`, `func2`, `func3`, and `func4` are all actually defined before you call `all()`, while the nested `if` or `and` expression approaches only require functions to be defined as long as the preceding function returned a true value.

Comment: However, it's worth mentioning that `func2()` won't be even looked up if `func1()` returns false, so that code works even if func2 isn't defined, while the `all()` approach will fail with a NameError if `func2` can't be found.