# Python style with long predicates to if

Tags: python, coding-style, formatting, styles, pep8

Consider this code:

```
if (something1 is not None and
    check_property(something_else) and
    dr_jekyll is mr_hyde):
    do_something(*args)
    other_statements()
```

It is obviously hard to tell where the predicate ends and the statements of the body begin, despite the code being written in PEP-8 manner.

We have devised two variants:

```
if ((something1 is not None) and
    (check_property(something_else)) and
    (dr_jekyll is mr_hyde)):
    do_something(*args)
    other_statements()
```

which is ugly and

```
if (something1 is not None and
        check_property(something_else) and
        dr_jekyll is mr_hyde):
    do_something(*args)
    other_statements()
```

which is also ugly.

I personally prefer #1, and my colleague uses #2.  Is there a non-ugly and PEP-8 compliant canonical solution which improves readability over the approaches listed above?

Comment: This question is primarily opinion based and thus off-topic on SO.

Comment: I think readability is very close to being quantifiable.

Comment: I think I incorrectly flagged this one. The answer from Alexander seems very plausible & to the point even thought the question is still more of opinion based.

Answer (score 3):

Change your if statement, using [all()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#all):

```
if all([something1 is not None, 
        check_property(something_else), 
        dr_jekyll is mr_hyde]):
    #do stuff...
```

Comment: This is more Pythonic

Comment: This is not equivalent to having the «raw» `if` statement, e. g. conditions such as `if name is not None and len(name) > 5`, which are very common, cannot be converted.

Comment: all([1 is not None, len(range(3))>1]) -> True

Comment: `name = None`
then
`all([name is not None, len(name) > 5])`?

Comment: Note that if `something1` **is** `None`, then `check_property()` will not be called. Your expression, however, **will** call `check_property()` (all expressions are evaluated) before returning `True` or `False`. This is an important distinction; `and` and `or` short-circuit, letting you use them to guard against exceptions.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19913290/python-if-versus-and-function-execution-order and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16069517/python-logical-evaluation-order-in-if-statement for more discussion on that.

Answer (score -1):

Depending on your context, you might not need `is not None`

```
>>> a = [1]
>>> if a:
        print "hello, world"


hello, world
>>> if a is not None:
        print "hello, world"


hello, world
>>>
```